# Plugin Development for Adobe Flash CS4 Professional

Tags: flash, plugins

Is it possible to create plug-in for "Adobe Flash Professional"..like you can do with Adobe Indesign or Adobe Illustrator ?
I googled a bit, but could not find any SDK ..maybe I did not searched hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash those plug-ins are called components. More on that here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/components/

If you want to build plug-ins for the Flash IDE google "Flash JSFL".